# How can I pass my class into its own constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class ActivityClass{
public:
    ActivityClass *from; 
    vector<ActivityClass> inside; 
    string name = "default";

    vector<string> tags;
    
    AcvitityClass(){} // def constructor
    ActivityClass(string aName, ActivityClass aFrom){
        name = aName;
        from = &aFrom;
        aFrom.addInside(this);
    }

    void addInside(ActivityClass toAdd); // stores other activity inside
};
```

So I want to create one of these objects and then create a new one and store it inside of the other with the constructor and I don't know how to do this.

It would look something like this:

```
ActivityClass activity1;
ActivityClass activitiy2("Buenas tardes", activity1);
```

So when I create the second activity it will be stored in the first one or at least store a pointer to the new class.

Comment: There's nothing to apologize for, your english is very good :)

Comment: If you need pointers internally, then changing the constructor to use pointers would help a lot here.

Comment: Does your `ActivityClass` really need to know about other classes?  Or would it be better to have it be simpler and let another class or construct hold the list/vector of classes for you?

Comment: Maybe the best option here is to restructure your class to avoid this pattern. You could have a container class which is composed of these `ActivitiyClass` objects, and the functionality from the `addInside` method can be implemented there?

Comment: yep my ActityClass has to know about other classes. I'm trying to create a folder based class, like storing a folder in other folder, that's why I want to store the activity class where an activity is stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a case for pointerizing all your arguments:

```
class ActivityClass {
public:
    ActivityClass *from;
    std::vector<ActivityClass*> inside; 
    std::string name = "default";

    std::vector<std::string> tags;
    
    ActivityClass() : from(nullptr) { }
    ActivityClass(const std::string& aName, ActivityClass* aFrom) : name(aName), from(aFrom) {
        aFrom->addInside(this);
    }

    void addInside(ActivityClass* toAdd) {
        inside.push_back(toAdd);
    }
};
```

Note I've added the `std::` prefix here to avoid ambiguity. `using namespace std` is a bad habit to get into.

A good habit to get into is passing things by reference, `const` if you can swing it, *especially* for strings.

Comment: You didn't completely fix syntax errors. Notably the typo in the constructor name, and the missing `std::` before `string`.

Comment: `std::vector<string> tags;` to `std::vector<std::string> tags;`

Comment: @NathanPierson Ah, got it.

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot. Henceforth I won't use "using namespace std". What I was looking at is how I could use the keyword "this" but it ended to be a pointer and not an object.

Comment: `this` really should be a reference, but fun fact: It was introduced so early in the design of C++ that references hadn't been invented yet, so it was, and remains, a pointer. This has been a source of much irritation ever since.